# How to validate a specific json structure in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I need a way to validate a specific formatted json that can represent a class (in my case Book class) strings using Jackson. Is there any way of doing this using jsonSchema? Or I have to do it in different way

`ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonSchema jsonSchema = mapper.generateJsonSchema(Book.class);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**

You need to use a third party library for this.

i.e. https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // this line will generate JSON schema from your class
    JsonNode schemaNode = objectMapper.generateJsonSchema(StageDetail.class).getSchemaNode();

    // make your JSON to JsonNode
    JsonNode jsonToValidate = JsonLoader.fromString(JSON_TO_VALIDATE);

    // validate it against the schema
    ProcessingReport validate = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getJsonSchema(schemaNode).validate(jsonToValidate);
    // validate.messages contains error massages
    System.out.println("Valid? " + validate.isSuccess());
```