# Jackson derealization with SpringBoot : To get field names present in request along with respective field mapping

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jackson

I have a requirement to throw different error in case of different scenarios like below, and there are many such fields not just 1.

e.g.

1. ```
      {
       "id": 1,
       "name": "nameWithSpecialChar$"
      }
   ```

   Here it should throw error for special character.
2. ```
      {
        "id": 1,
         "name": null
      }
   ```

   Here throw field null error.
3. ```
      {
       "id": 1
      }
   ```

   Here throw field missing error.

Handling, 1st and 2nd scenario is easy, but for 3rd one, is there any way we can have a List of name of fields that were passed in input json at the time of serialization itself with Jackson?

One way, I am able to do it is via mapping request to JsonNode and then check if nodes are present for required fields and after that deserialize that JsonNode manually and then validate rest of the members as below.

```
    public ResponseEntity myGetRequest(@RequestBody JsonNode requestJsonNode) {

    if(!requestJsonNode.has("name")){
      throw some error;
    }

    MyRequest request = ObjectMapper.convertValue(requestJsonNode, MyRequest .class);
    validateIfFieldsAreInvalid(request);
```

But I do not like this approach, is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) and use it to validate your object? Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874944/how-to-validate-a-specific-json-structure-in-jackson) helps.

Comment: That won't work, as I need to throw different error for each invalid field(s) and even separate error for missing, null and incorrect value.

Comment: You can. That's the strength of using schema. You can distinguish between errors. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) and validate your object against it. In your example, your schema may look like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "description": "The identifier",
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "description": "The item name",
      "type": "string",
      "pattern": "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "id", "name" ]
}
```

To validate your object, you could use the [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator) library. This library is built on Jackson. Since you're using Spring Boot anyway, you already have Jackson imported.

The example code looks more or less like this:

```java
String schema = "<define your schema here>";
String data = "<put your data here>";

JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
JsonSchema jsonSchema = factory.getJsonSchema(m.readTree(schema));
JsonNode json = m.readTree(data);
ProcessingReport report = jsonSchema.validate(json);

System.out.println(report);
```

The report includes detailed errors for different input cases. For example, with this input

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "nameWithSpecialChar$"
}
```

this output is printed out

```
--- BEGIN MESSAGES ---
error: ECMA 262 regex "^[a-zA-Z]*$" does not match input string "nameWithSpecialChar$"
    level: "error"
    schema: {"loadingURI":"#","pointer":"/properties/name"}
    instance: {"pointer":"/name"}
    domain: "validation"
    keyword: "pattern"
    regex: "^[a-zA-Z]*$"
    string: "nameWithSpecialChar$"
---  END MESSAGES  ---
```

Or instead of just printing out the report, you can loop through all errors and have your specific logic

```java
for (ProcessingMessage message : report) {
    // Add your logic here
}
```

You could check the [example code](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fge/jsonschema/examples) to gain more information about how to use the library.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use this. Accepting your answer now.